# Redirecting url with Puppeteer by changing url

Tags: redirect, puppeteer

I am trying to get change my request url and see the new url in the response

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
    if (interceptedRequest.url().includes('some-string')) {
       interceptedRequest.respond({
          status: 302,
          headers: {
            url: 'www.new.url.com'
          },
        })
    }
    interceptedRequest.continue()
  });

 page.on('response', response => {
    console.log(response.url())
 })
 await page.goto('www.orginal.url.com')
// some code omitted
})();
```

In the *interceptedRequest.respond* method I'm trying to update the value of the url. Originally I was trying:

`interceptedRequest.continue({url: 'www.new.url.com'})`

but that way is not long supported in the current version of Puppeteer.
I was expecting to get *[www.new.url.com](http://www.new.url.com)* in the response, but I actually get the orignial url with  *[www.new.url.com](http://www.new.url.com)* appended to the end.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me. You need to change url to location

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
    if (interceptedRequest.url().includes('some-string')) {
       interceptedRequest.respond({
          status: 302,
          headers: {
            location: 'www.new.url.com'
          },
        })
    }
  });

 page.on('response', response => {
    console.log(response.url())
 })
 await page.goto('www.orginal.url.com')
// some code omitted
})();
```